# How to get sum of char values produced in a loop?

Tags: java, arrays, sum, character

Sorry if the title is misleading or is confusing, but here is my dilemma.
I am inputting a string, and want to assign a value to each capitalized letter in the alphabet (A=1, .. Z=26) and then add the values of each letter in that string.

**Example:** ABCD = 10  (since 1 + 2 + 3 + 4)

But I don't know how to add all the values in the string

**NOTE**: This is only for **capitalized** letters and strings

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scannerTest = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a name here: ");

        String str = scannerTest.nextLine();

        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        int temp_integer = 64;

        for (char c : ch) {
            int temp = (int) c;

               if (temp <= 90 & temp >= 65){
            int sum = (temp - temp_integer);
            System.out.println(sum);
        }   
      }
    }
}
```

So, as you can see I print out the sum for each time its looped,
meaning: if I input "AB", the output will be 1 and 2.

However, I want to go a step further, and add these two values together, but I'm stumped, any suggestions or help? (**NOTE:** this is not a assignment or anything, just practising problem sets)

Comment: You realize that this line: `if (temp <= 90 & temp >= 65);` has no purpose into your code right? An `if` statement must have at least one line after it without the brackets without that it is just a code that will make no difference.

Comment: Since you are able to get the integer value for each capitalized letter already, why not just add them up in the for loop to get the sum?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Java is build upon ASCII's characters, so in ASCII the number 65 represents "A" and 90 represents "Z", and I need it to that parameter or I'll get wrong values when/if they enter lowercase letters

Comment: I know that, I'm aware of that since I'm a programmer since 1989, started on MS-Basic. You didn't understand what I mean. Read it slowly and try to  understand what it means.

Comment: @BOND I don't know the code to do that, I'm a beginner in Java so I apologize, the code I wrote prints the sum of value of EACH character, but I don't know what to write to print the sum of the values of each character

Comment: Your code doesn't print the sum, it prints the current capitalized letter integer value MINUS your 64 constant which will give 1 to 26

Comment: @JorgeCampos  Ah okay, sorry I must've accidentally added a ";" instead of a "{"  , I've fixed it now thank you

Comment: @JorgeCampos and yes that's what I meant, it prints the current capitalized letter integer value - 64, I'm trying now to find the code that will allow me to find the sum

Comment: @Theo no problem. I was adding an answer without code, just directions since you are learning. But people here is eager for votes. You already have two answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer to use the character literals. You know that the range is `A` to `Z` (`1` to `26`), so you can subtract 'A' from each `char` (but you need to add 1 because it doesn't start at `0`). I would also call `toUpperCase` on the input line. Something like,

```
Scanner scannerTest = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a name here: ");
String str = scannerTest.nextLine().toUpperCase();
int sum = 0;
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
        sum += 1 + ch - 'A';
    }
}
System.out.printf("The sum of %s is %d%n", str, sum);
```

Which I tested with your example

```
Enter a name here: 
ABCD
The sum of ABCD is 10
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you, one question though, what does "%s" and "%d%n" do?

Comment: [Formatting (The Java Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html), *`s` formats any value as a string.* and *`d` formats an integer value as a decimal value.* and *`n` outputs a platform-specific line terminator.*

Answer (score 2):

Using 64 to represent the character before 'A' in the ascii table is difficult to understand, you can perform substration between characters in Java directly.

So if 'A' represent 1, then just do **c - 'A' + 1** will give you the corresponding integer value for each capitalized letter.

To get the sum, just sum up: initialize the sum as 0, and in the for loop, add increment sum by the value you calculated. You can use the incremental assignment operation: **+=**

```
Scanner scannerTest = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a name here: ");

    String str = scannerTest.nextLine();

    char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
    int sum = 0;
    for (char c : ch) {
        sum += c - 'A' + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: this works thank you! The only thing is that I can still input lower case letters, but that can be easily fixed with the method toUpperCase()

Answer (score 0):

**Change only your for to these:**

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++){
    sum += (int) ch[i] - 96;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

The `sum += (int) ch[i] - 96;` is because the char `a` is the value 97, as your say, you want char a corresponde to 1, note that `a` is different than `A`

**Check the char value here:** https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

This was tested and worked fine! Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this (in C programming language) which you can easily modify for other programming languages:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int i;
  char word[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  unsigned int sum = 0;
  unsigned int charVal;

  for (i=0; i < strlen(word); ++i) {
    charVal = word[i] - 'A' + 1;
    printf("Value of %c is %d\n", word[i], charVal);
    sum += charVal;
  }
  printf("Sum of %s = %d\n", word, sum);
  return(0);
}
```

The trick is to take the character value, subtract the baseline 'A' value and add 1 to arrive at your calculation range:

```
charVal = word[i] - 'A' + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieve the same in a concise way by employing Java 8's lambda functions

```
String str = "ABCD";
int sum = str.chars()
                .filter(c -> c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                .map(c -> 1 + c - 'A')
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```